# Best zip compression level for JSON or text files?

Tags: json, compression, zip, deflate

Has anyone performed some tests (size and speed) for the selection of the 'best' compression [level](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.zip.Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION) of the Java zip deflater, to be used on general/miscellaneous JSON or text files? If yes which level do you recommend? Thanks.

Comment: @trojanfoe No, that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could not find a precise answer to this question, but someone came with something [close enough](http://tukaani.org/lzma/benchmarks.html).

Comment: Awesome, but why did he not draw the effort/compression ratio graph his results were crying out for...